# JSON token name with @

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

I am using Jackson to serialize a JAXB generated class to JSON within Jersey. Whilst the generated JSON works fine some of the token names have an @ before them.

e.g.

xsd defines:

```
<xs:element name="uid" type="xs:long"/>
```

this gets generated in the java class as:

```
private Long uid;
```

with associated getters and setters. Using the standard Jackson ObjectMapper (with defualt configuration) the serialized JSON is:

```
"@uid":  1
```

I have read through the Jackson documentation and am unable to find anything that indicates why this is the case. Is there any way to get the JSON to serialize as uid rather than @uid? I suppose I also need to understand what the meaning of the @ is because some properties have the @ and some dont.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is probably due to the fact that this is an XML attribute (and that, if I'm not mistaken, attribute names and element names in XML cannot have this character). Try and ask on the devel mailing list if there are ways to customize attribute names during serialization.

Comment: Include full signature of a class that gets serialized as you described. Make sure to include all fields along with their respective annotations.

Answer (score 0):

This is not enough information to know for sure. First thing is that you must show actual Java object (POJO) you are using -- Jackson does not use XML Schema for anything. It's all about getters, setters and annotations.

But it is also possible that you may not even be using Jackson, since this is typical behavior by XML-based tools like `Jettison` and `XStream`; they tend to add at-sign to distinguish "elements from attributes" (which is XML-specific difference that these tools want to retain).